# Posição do scroll do RecyclerView com Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Eu estou listando dados do *Firebase* em uma `RecyclerView`, mas ao adicionar dados ou remover, os dados se repetem na lista. Utilizei o `clear();` ou `lista.removeAll(lista);` para limpar antes de preencher só que a lista é atualizada e volta a posição do scroll para o começo. Alguém tem uma ideia de como evitar isso?
 Segue o meu codigo:

```
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //
        Escala.removeAll(Escala);
        for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            ModelEscala model = singleSnapshot.getValue(ModelEscala.class);
            Escala.add(model);
            recyclerViewAdapterEscalas = new RecyclerViewAdapterEscalas(getActivity(), Escala, mImageLoader);
            recyclerViewAdapterEscalas.notifyDataSetChanged();

            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterEscalas);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};

mDataBase.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema esta sendo no metódo `recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterEscalas);` o ideal seria instanciar o adapter e atribuir para a recyclerView somente 1 vez, para atualizar os dados você só precisa manipular seu ArrayList e notificar o adapter (`recyclerViewAdapterEscalas.notifyDataSetChanged();`)

Exemplo:

```
recyclerViewAdapterEscalas = new RecyclerViewAdapterEscalas(getActivity(), Escala, mImageLoader);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapterEscalas);

ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {       
        Escala.removeAll(Escala);
        for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            ModelEscala model = singleSnapshot.getValue(ModelEscala.class);
            Escala.add(model);
            recyclerViewAdapterEscalas.notifyDataSetChanged();            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};

mDataBase.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

Tente desta forma, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Guilherme Montanher muito obrigado por responder minha pergunta você é o cara resolveu meu probrema!